# PostgreSQL query with subqueries

Tags: postgresql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reONq.png)
Here is the diagram of the database. I have to write a query from this question:
What is each readers most read genre?

```
SELECT profile_name, genre, COUNT(genre) AS count FROM profile p
JOIN book_read br on p.id = br.profile_id
JOIN book b on br.book_id = b.id
JOIN book_genre bg on b.id = bg.book_id
JOIN genre g on bg.genre_id = g.id
WHERE br.status = 'read'
GROUP BY profile_name, genre
```

But this query gives me all the counts of books for each genre per `profile_name`, but i need to get the most read genre for each `profile_name`.

Comment: Try adding a [Distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) (profile_name) clause to your select.  And of course the necessary `order by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the count per profile per genre, we can use this data to get the most read genre per profile using 2 `WITH` and an `inner join` to grab the data needed :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT profile_name, genre, COUNT(genre) AS count 
  FROM profile p
  JOIN book_read br on p.id = br.profile_id
  JOIN book b on br.book_id = b.id
  JOIN book_genre bg on b.id = bg.book_id
  JOIN genre g on bg.genre_id = g.id
  WHERE br.status = 'read'
  GROUP BY profile_name, genre
),
cte2 as (
  select profile_name, max(count) as count
  from cte
  group by profile_name
)
select c.*
from cte c
inner join cte2 c2 on c2.profile_name = c.profile_name and c2.count = c.count
```